# How to use jquery ui slider to change the class of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

```
    <div id="slider" align="center" style="width:50%;margin-left:20%;" ></div>
    <div id="1" class="res1" style="margin:10px auto">
    </div>
  <script>
 $(function() {
    $( "#slider" ).slider({
    animate:"fast", 
    value:0,
    min: 0,
    max: 50,
    step: 25,
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        if(($("#1").hasClass('res1'))&& (ui.value=25)){
            $(".res1").toggleClass('res1 res2');
            }
        else if(($("#1").hasClass('res2'))&& (ui.value=50)){
            $(".res2").toggleClass('res2 res3');
            }
                else if(($("#1").hasClass('res2'))&& (ui.value=50)){
            $(".res2").toggleClass('res2 res3');
            }

        }
    });
```

});

Made the above changes and now the class of div "1" get changed with sliding.But I have to change the class of div "1" to "res2" when ui.slider value is 25 and to class "res3" when the ui.slider value is 50.I used the above code.But I couldnt get the output as desired.Please help

Comment: do you think its fine to use id="#1" and using selector $("#1")?

Comment: You should ask a new question if you have new requirement. Your modification of question changes the meaning of answer completely. in short they are deemed incorrect, So I strongly suggest to ASK a new question

Answer (score 1):

You have missed `''` (Quotes) in function parameter `hasClass(res1)`.

Thus use

```
    if($("#1").hasClass('res1')){
      $("#1").toggleClass('res1 res2');
    }
```

And Also Remove `#` from ID attribute thus use

```
<div id="1" class="res1" style="margin:10px auto">
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/aSgCz/)

---

Additionally, if you want to use

```
<div id="#1" class="res1" style="margin:10px auto"></div>
```

Change your selector to `$("#\\#1")`, i.e. You need to escape `#` with `\\`

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/aSgCz/1/) with # as literal

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problmes

```
<div id="1" class="res1" style="margin:10px auto"></div>
<!-- the id started with #-->
```

then

```
$(function () {
    $("#slider").slider({
        animate: "fast",
        value: 0,
        min: 0,
        max: 50,
        step: 25,
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            //res1 was not enclosed within ''
            if ($("#1").hasClass('res1')) {
                $("#1").toggleClass('res1 res2');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/KdNz5/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you are doing 2 wrong, 1- is `#1` and another in js `hasClass(res1)`

HTML

```
<div id="slider" align="center" style="width:50%;margin-left:20%;" >ds</div>
    <div id="1" class="res1" style="margin:10px auto">sds
    </div>
```

JQuery

```
$(function() {
$( "#slider" ).slider({
    animate:"fast", 
    value:0,
    min: 0,
    max: 50,
    step: 25,
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        if($("#1").hasClass('res1')){
            $(".res1").toggleClass('res2');
            }
        }
    });
 });
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MPXVG/)